# Discord.js Urban Dictionary Node Fetch

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to create an Urban Dictionary command for my bot making it so users can look up a specific word or phrase

```
(prefix)urban <args>
```

I am using the Commando command handler, node-fetch, and querystring. The links are at the bottom.
Here is my code:

```
const commando = require('discord.js-commando')
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const queryString = require('query-string')

module.exports = class UrbanDictionaryCommand extends commando.Command {
    constructor(client) {
        super(client, {
            name: 'urbandictionary',
            aliases: ['urban'],
            group: 'misc',
            memberName: 'urbandictionary',
            description: 'Shows the urban dictionary entry for a word or phrase'
        })
    }

    async run(message, args) {
        if(!args) {
            message.reply('You need to specify something to search')
            return
        }

        const { list } = await fetch(`https://api.urbandictionary.com/v0/define?${args}`).then(response => response.json())

        try {
            const [answer] = list
            const trim = (str, max) => ((str.length > max) ? `${str.slice(0, max - 3)}...` : str)

            const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                embed.setTitle(answer.word)
                embed.setURL(answer.permalink)
                embed.addFields({
                    name: 'Definition',
                    value: trim(answer.definition, 1024),
                    inline: false
                }, {
                    name: 'Example',
                    value: trim(answer.example, 1024),
                    inline: false
                }, {
                    name: 'Rating',
                    value: `${answer.thumbs_up}  || ${answer.thumbs_down} `,
                    inline: false
                })
                embed.setFooter(`Command issued by ${message.author.tag}`, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
            message.channel.send(embed)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            message.channel.send(`No results found for ${args}`)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute the command in my Discord server, I receive this error message

```
TypeError: list is not iterable
    at UrbanDictionaryCommand.run (C:\Users\Owner\OneDrive\Desktop\(BotName)\cmds\misc\urban.js:26:30)
```

I am not entirely sure what the issue is with the command

Here are the links to the npms for the used features:

```
Node-Fetch: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch
Query-String: https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string
```

Comment: Could you try `console.log`ging `list` to see what it is? Or maybe not destructure it and log the response?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `.then()`, the variables inside aren't returned.

```
const { list } = await fetch(`https://api.urbandictionary.com/v0/define?${args}`).then(response => response.json())
```

the `response.json()` in the above code is local, "list" therefore is undefined.

```
const response = await fetch(`https://api.urbandictionary.com/v0/define?${args}`)
const {list} = await response.json()
```

And on a completely unrelated note, make sure to restrict this command only to NSFW channels, since urban dictionary may return NSFW data, and its against discord TOS to put that data in non-NSFW channels.

Comment: I have checked this, and `.then` actually changes the value returned as a `Promise`. The exact piece of code I used is `Promise.resolve({ abc: "def" }).then(value => value.abc)` and it did return `"def"`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly except for the api call the URL should be ...

```
https://api.urbandictionary.com/v0/define?term=
```